# Morris chart change color when pass goal

Tags: javascript, charts, colors

In my morris chart I would like the lines change their color from blue to red when they pass the goal lines.

I have no idea how to start doing this. Here is the code of my chart:

```
var chart = Morris.Line({
            element: element1 ,
            data: json,
            hideHover: 'auto',
            xkey: 'data_inicio',
            goals: [25,50],
            ykeys: colunas,
            pointSize:0,
            lineColors:['#000080','#228b22','#228b22','#ff7f50','#ff7f50'],
            labels: designacao_colunas,
            ymax: biggest,
            ymin : lowest,
            smooth: false
        });
```

Comment: Morris doesn't support this out of the box (there's very little it does), you'll probably want to address Raphaël directly and override the drawing directives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Morris charts, but you may want to consider techniques used in other charting tools: breaking each line into two lines. Use the goal value to split each line into two lines, one from below the goal to the goal, another line from the goal and above the goal. Then you can use different colors for below and above the goal line.

In traditional charting tools like Excel it would look like this:

[image]